# Is the dimension of a linear system $|D|$ always finite?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $M$ be a compact complex manifold and $D=\sum a_i V_i$   a divisor on $M.$ If $|D|$ is the set of effective divisors linearly equivalent to $D,$ we know that 
$$|D|\cong \mathbb{P}( H^0 (M,  {\cal O} ([D]))).$$

Is the dimension of the linear system $|D|$ always finite?

Comment: Hartshorne's textbook Theorem II.5.19

Comment: @Chen: Hartshorne's result concerns projective algebraic manifolds, not general compact complex manifolds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\mathcal O(D)$ is a coherent analytic sheaf, one may apply Cartan-Serre's finiteness theorem:

*If $X$ is a compact holomorphic variety and $\mathcal F$  is a coherent analytic sheaf on $X$ , then $\operatorname {dim}_\mathbb C H^p(X,\mathcal F)\lt \infty$ for all $p\geq 0$ .*

Notice that $X$ is not necessarily a manifold: it may have singularities.
Your question is, of course, answered by taking the value $p=0$ since $H^0(X,\mathcal F)=\Gamma(X,\mathcal F)$.
The main tool for proving this theorem is, somewhat unexpectedly, a rather difficult functional analysis result by Laurent Schwartz on the perturbation of a continuous surjective morphism  between Fréchet spaces by a compact morphism.
[Here](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/SHC/SHC_1953-1954__6_/SHC_1953-1954__6__A17_0/SHC_1953-1954__6__A17_0.pdf) is a report by Cartan himself on his joint theorem, extracted from his celebrated Séminaire .
A more recent reference is   [Taylor's excellent book](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Several_Complex_Variables_with_Connectio.html?id=i8lUNpZ379MC&redir_esc=y), page 302.

Comment: Thank you for a great answer, and for the amazing references.

Comment: You are welcome,  Joe.